# Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Tags: java, queue, jms, weblogic, jms-topic

I'm trying to read `JMS queue` from a server, I am able to ping the IP and port from my machine but when I execute my queue program it throws the below error any help would be appreciated.

```
public class QueueReceive implements MessageListener
{
 public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
 public final static String JMS_FACTORY="NotifyDestQCF"; 
 public final static String QUEUE="NOTIFY_DEST_QUEUE"; 
 private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
 private QueueConnection qcon;
 private QueueSession qsession;
 private QueueReceiver qreceiver;
 private Queue queue;
 private boolean quit = false;
 public void onMessage(Message msg)
 {
    try {
     String msgText;
     if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
       msgText = ((TextMessage)msg).getText();
     } else {
       msgText = msg.toString();
     }
     System.out.println("Message Received: "+ msgText );
     if (msgText.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
       synchronized(this) {
         quit = true;
         this.notifyAll(); // Notify main thread to quit
       }
     }
    } catch (JMSException jmse) {
     System.err.println("An exception occurred: "+jmse.getMessage());
    }
 }
 public void init(Context ctx, String queueName)
    throws NamingException, JMSException
 {
    qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
    qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
    qreceiver = qsession.createReceiver(queue);
    qreceiver.setMessageListener(this);
    qcon.start();
 }

 public void close()throws JMSException
 {
    qreceiver.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
     System.out.println("Usage: java examples.jms.queue.QueueReceive WebLogicURL");
     return;
    }
     InitialContext ic = getInitialContext(args[0]);
    QueueReceive qr = new QueueReceive();
    qr.init(ic, QUEUE);

    System.out.println(
        "JMS Ready To Receive Messages (To quit, send a \"quit\" message).");

    // Wait until a "quit" message has been received.
    synchronized(qr) {
     while (! qr.quit) {
       try {
         qr.wait();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
     }
    }
    qr.close();
 }
 private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url)
    throws NamingException
 {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    System.out.print("Gmail mohanraj rasappan");
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    return new InitialContext(env);
 }
}
```

Args[0] is t3://172.26.169.57:7001. Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationExce ption
[Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at
remote endpoint]
        at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:189)
        at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:195)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at client.QueueReceive.init(QueueReceive.java:76)
        at client.QueueReceive.main(QueueReceive.java:109) Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:248
)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:185)
        ... 4 more
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You are using the RMI protocol to lookup something that isn't an RMI Registry. Code please.

Comment: Hi Scott_lotus , Thank you for your response , below is my code.

Comment: I don't know who or what Scott_lotus may be, but code that forms part of a question must be posted in the question. Such code is certainly not an answer and should not be posted as such.

Comment: Thanks EJP , i'm new to Stackoverflow .. i did not notice that ..

Comment: could you please help me out..

Comment: given text box here does not hold entire code!! so i put it under the answer..

Comment: Strange that it fitted OK when I did it.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to add in comments section ,Ok , now coming to the problem , the same code is working with my localhost . I can able to read messages . But I could not able to do that with Weblogic server .